# Regex function to replace characters to HEX code

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, zpl

I write a code to use Zebra printer, i need print using a special characters with iso-8859-1.

To print labels i use RawPrinterHelp class and work done, but when have a special characters do not work.

I find the table in this link https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl, and write a function to convert the specials characters to hex utf8 using regex codes in my label.

my function is

```
Public Shared Function GetRawString(str As String) As String
    Dim s As String = vbNullString
    s = Regex.Replace(str, "[\p{L}-[a-zA-Z]]", Function(m) String.Join(String.Empty, m.Value.[Select](Function(c) String.Format("_c3_{0:x2}", Convert.ToInt32(c))).ToArray()))
    Return s
End Function
```

But this resulted converted string not work.

The question is what is the correct string for replace "*c3*{0:x2}" in my function for convert to format in the link?

Answer (score 0):

I can't use regex to resolve this, i created my own function for future reference this a answer.

```
Public Shared Function GetRawString(str As String) As String
    Dim l() As String = {"á", "à", "ã", "â", "é", "ê", "í", "ó", "ô", "õ", "ú", "ç", "Á", "À", "Ã", "Â", "É", "Ê", "Í", "Ó", "Ô", "Õ", "Ú", "Ç", "°"}
    Dim c() As String = {"_c3_a1", "_c3_a0", "_c3_a3", "_c3_a2", "_c3_a9", "_c3_aa", "_c3_ad", "_c3_b3", "_c3_b4", "_c3_b5", "_c3_ba", "_c3_a7", "_c3_81", "_c3_80", "_c3_83", "_c3_82", "_c3_89", "_c3_8a", "_c3_8d", "_c3_93", "_c3_94", "_c3_95", "_c3_9a", "_c3_87", "_c2_b0"}
    Dim s As String = vbNullString

    For i = LBound(l) To UBound(l)
        str = str.Replace(l(i), c(i))
    Next

    Return str

End Function
```